# Why does `await coro()` block but `await task` does not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Why is it necessary to wrap a Python coroutine in a "task" in order for it to execute concurrently?  I expected awaiting a coroutine to be concurrent by default.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(f"{time.strftime('%X')}: {what}")


async def main():
    # this blocks! no different then subroutines, executes the first coroutine,
    # then the second
    await say_after(3, "one")
    await say_after(3, "two")

    print()

    # this executes the coroutines concurrently
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, "three"))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(3, "four"))

    await t1
    await t2

asyncio.run(main())

# Output:
# 22:15:27: one
# 22:15:30: two
#
# 22:15:33: three
# 22:15:33: four
```

Comment: You are explicitly awaiting the completion of the first two calls. But you are starting `t2` before awaiting `t1`.

Comment: which are coroutines...  I'm also explicitly awaiting the second two calls, which are tasks... why is it necessary to wrap them in tasks to achieve concurrency, that's the whole point of coroutines?

Comment: not following when you say I'm starting t2 before awaiting t1, the calls are identical other than wrapping them in create_task() and creating Task objects first

Comment: No, they are not. You create both task and then you await them. While you await `t1` (takes 3s) `t2` runs already. When `await t1` returns, `t2` is also nearly finished, resulting in a total time for both of a little more than 3s.

Comment: `await` means wait, so when you await a coroutine, execution _cannot_ proceed until it is done. The same applies to awaiting a task, but the difference is that the **other** task (`t2`) can proceed while you're awaiting the first one, because `create_task()` spawned it in the background. When you await both coroutines directly, the second coroutine has not yet had a chance to execute while you await the first one.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: it's not enough to just await _tasks_ to get parallelism; for example, `await asyncio.create_task(first()); await asyncio.create_task(second())` will have the same result (sequential execution) as `await first(); await second()`. With the code that runs in parallel the important bit is that you create both tasks _in advance_, and then await them. Just calling the coroutines doesn't do that because coroutines are lightweight and aren't automatically scheduled to run when called. (This is in contrast to async functions in JavaScript, but similar to Rust futures.)

Comment: user4815162342 thanks, I'm slowly starting to grok it, has definitely been tricky to wrap my head around.  I was under the impression that *await* is what schedules a coroutine for concurrent execution, and it sounds like this is the root of my confusion... you have to _first_ schedule via create_task, _then_ await, am I starting to understand correctly?